# Dynanmically update specific rails attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, hash, nomethoderror

I have a constant hash `P_FACT_MAP` and an array of keys of the previous hash `product_params[:product_factors]`. In `P_FACT_MAP` all values are mapped to another value or an array of values which are the attribute names of the `ProductFactor` table.

```
P_FACT_MAP = {
  :x => %w[something]
  :y => %w[something2, something]
  :z => %w[something 3, something1]
  ...
  ...
}
```

I'm trying to update the dynamic attribute values by doing:

```
ProductFactor.v << product_params[:p_id]
```

The complete method code:

```
ProductFactor::P_FACT_MAP.collect.do |k, v|
  puts "Value #{v}"
  if product_params[:product_factors].include? k
     v.each do |f|
       @coach_recommendation_factor.send(f) << @coach.id
   end
end
```

But it doesn't recognize the attribute name v and I get the following error:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `v' for #<Class:0x007f95de9b8180>)
```

Is it not possible to update the value of an attribute dynamically or do I have to take a completely different approach to reach that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`'v'` is not a method for your `ProductFactor` class. If you are trying to use the variable `v` from `|k, v|` then replace `ProductFactor.v` with `ProductFactor.send(v)`

Answer (score 0):

I believe this line should be

```
ProductFactor::P_FACT_MAP.collect.do |k, v|
```

replaced with

```
ProductFactor::P_FACT_MAP.each do |k, v|
```